# Gitlab Pages custom domain SSL

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to add TLS/SSL to my custom domain on Gitlab. Currently it says my site is available at https://yodel.co, but when I go there it says the certificate is invalid. How do I go about validating the certificate?

In the [docs](http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/pages/README.html#secure-your-custom-domain-website-with-tls) (also pictured) it says there are keys to add from your admin when setting up a new domain. However I'm not sure where to get these keys as I am the admin.

**My Gitlab Pages**
[image: My Pages]

**Gitlab docs screenshot**
[image: Documentation says there's keys to add?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this keys through https://startssl.com/, following these steps: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/06/24/secure-gitlab-pages-with-startssl/.

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889365/gitlab-pages-daemon-where-is-home-git